# Item Created Event for Web database and send email

Tags: exm, events

I have a requirement to send a email to subscribers once a blog will be available publicly. Requirement is very specific that email will be send only one time when item is created, not on update or multiple publishing. We will use EXM automated campaign to send email through code . I would like to know best approach to track the availability of item in web database and send email.

Answer (score 3):

I would use item:created event handler, because this is only fired once, when the item is published. (Publish creates the item in web database). 
It isn't fired multiple times, even if you create a new version from the item or republish the item instead of smart publish.

```
 public void OnItemCreated(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        Item item = ((Sitecore.Data.Events.ItemCreatedEventArgs)(Event.ExtractParameter(args, 0))).Item;

        if (item == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (item.Database.Name == "web")
        {
            // Send your mail
        }
    }
```

Do not forget to register this at "item:created" event in your config

Comment: Arvai, unfortunately this code will not work as item create fires only when item get created in master. I didn't find any code/event where i can capture itemcreated event for web database.

Comment: I've tested with Sitecore 9 and it is fired when item created in web database (by a publish). if you tried, can you share your config and your code? and yes, this event is also fired when item is created in master db, but you check the current database is web or master.